# Custom WordPress Single Post Page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a website here: http://jordanvalentin.com/testing.php

All of the pages are just plain php that are connected to WordPress to pull the posts and content of pages.

When on the main page, when you click the post title it goes to the single.php of the WordPress theme installed.

How do I go about creating a custom single.php that is styled similarly to my other pages? Is it as easy as editing the single.php of the current theme? Or is it best practice to create my own entire theme rather than just connecting WP to certain pages?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Child theme for your Wordpress theme and edit your single.php in your child theme folder. More informations in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Once your child theme has been created, you can simply duplicate the original single.php file and make your edits without damaging your theme, and without losing your edits if you update your theme.

Comment: The thing is I'm not using a theme. There is a default one installed. But I just have php pages that are pulling data from WordPress. Maybe that's what you're saying and I just don't understand :(

Comment: What do you mean, you're creating a theme for other users? If not, you're always using a theme, otherwise nothing would be displayed on your screen. Are you familiar with Child themes? You need to create a child theme from your main theme and then edit your single.php in there. To do so, go to your Wordpress root folder/wp-content/themes . Create a child theme folder in this "themes" directory, for ex twentyfourteen-child if you're using twentyfourteen. Now copy single.php from your main theme directory into your child theme one. You'll be able to edit it without altering the theme core files.

Comment: I'm not using a theme. I have a wp installed in a directory called blog. I also have an index.php file that just includes wp-blog-header.php from that blog directory. I then just grab the data from the WP backend by, for example,                                       <?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=DSC&orderby=date');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<h3><?php the_title(); echo "<br />";?></h3>

Comment: I don't understand, are you developping your own theme or CMS? If not, connect to your wp-admin, then go to Appearance / Themes and tell me what you see. Is there a theme activated?